# How to convert png to geotiff?

Tags: png, qgis, geotiff

I have a PNG image file.I want to convert it to GeoTiff.  I installed QGIS software but i can not use it and i dont know how to Georeference the image. Please help me. is there any online software ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a pretty good tutorial with step by step instructions on how to georeference an image in the GUI.

http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do it instantly, the quickest option will be via the link below:

https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/png-to-gtiff

unfortunately, the tool won't let you convert more than 3 files monthly or more than 5MB files in total.

If you wish to do the conversion for free, there is a tool available here:

[geoconverter.hsr.ch/raster](http://geoconverter.hsr.ch)

but the quality is much worst than by Mygeodata cloud. However if you need it for the boundaries only, then it should be fine.

[image]