# convert PNG to GeoTIFF with GDAL

Tags: image-processing, gdal, qgis

I have a PNG that I am trying to make into a GeoTIFF. My result ends up being an all-black image with the correct bounds and size (all channels min & max pixel values are 0).

My source image is a 16bit per channel PNG (UInt16). Below is my command. Do I need to do something differently?  My image is 1760width x 3466height in the San Diego, CA area.

`gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -r near -of GTiff -te -117.119811 32.700376 -117.059864 32.799896 -ts 1760 3466 -to SRC_METHOD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM 11bit.png OUTPUT.tif`

Comment: This was helpful.  Is there an easier way?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47196793/1469613

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to convert a PNG image with known geographic coordinates of its corners to a GeoTIFF file of the same size as the original image, you can use `gdal_translate`.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_ullr -117.119811 32.700376 -117.059864 32.799896 11bit.png OUTPUT.tif
```